# Finding astroids

Tags: plotting, fitting, polynomials, geometry

An **astroid** is a particular mathematical curve: a hypocycloid with four cusps.

Given a lot of data points I'm trying to fit such a curve to the data.
As an astroid is also an **algebraic curve** of grade 6 I used `LinearModelFit`:

```
points=Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/Bi3DPvNj","Data"];
lin ={ #1 + #2, #1^2 + #2^2, #1^3 + #2^3, #1^4 + #2^4, #1^5 + #2^5, #1^6 + #2^6, #1 #2, #1^2 #2 + #1 #2^2, #1^3 #2 + #1 #2^3, #1^4 #2 + #1 #2^4, #1^5 #2 + #1 #2^5, #1^2 #2^2, #1^3 #2^2 + #1^2 #2^3, #1^4 #2^2+ #1^2 #2^4, #1^3 #2^3} & @@@ points;
lm = LinearModelFit[lin,Prepend[Table[Subscript[a,i],{i,1,14}],1],Table[Subscript[a,i],{i,1,14}]];
Quiet@lm["ANOVATable"]
```

Which results in

```
w[x_, y_] :=lm["BestFitParameters"].{1, x+y,  x^2+y^2, x^3+ y^3, x^4+ y^4, x^5+ y^5, x^6+y^6, x y, x y^2+ x^2 y, x y^3+ x^3 y, x y^4+x^4 y, x y^5+x^5 y, x^2 y^2, x^2 y^3+x^3 y^2, x^2 y^4+ x^4 y^2}-x^3 y^3;
ContourPlot[w[x, y] == 0, {x, 0.8, 1.0}, {y, 0.8, 1.0}, Prolog -> Point[points],ContourStyle->{Red},PlotPoints->109,ImageSize->Large]
```

[image]

Actually, the fit is okay, but `ContourPlot` seems to struggle with this polynomial as can be seen near 2 of the cusps (green). Is there a work-around?
(Using many `PlotPoints` works, but takes very long.)

Comment: Looks like it got clipped by `ContourPlot`, rather than it being an issue with the fit.  Could be both, though.

Comment: With `PlotPoints -> 1000, MaxRecursion -> 4` (~7 min): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIfuZ.png

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks a lot, I couldn't use so many plot points. So, we know the fit is okay. `ContourPlot` seems to have some issues with those curves.

Comment: `ContourPlot` works on the intermediate-value-theorem principle: it draws the curve between sample points when the function values lies on opposite sides of the contour value (f == 0 in this case).  It takes a lot of refinement to get enough points inside and outside a cusp to draw a cusp accurately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternative method for visualization and faster than `ContourPlot` with `PlotPoints -> 1000` for nearly the same high quality in this case:

```
Needs@"NDSolve`FEM`"
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[
    w[x, y] < 0 && 0.8 < x < 1.0 && 0.8 < y < 1.0, {x, y}], 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01];
Show[
 Graphics[{Point[points]}],
 bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> Red]],
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{0.8, 1.0}, {0.8, 1.0}}
 ]
```

[image]

Another way, using `NDSolve`, which can get all the way into the cusps:

```
icy = 0.9;
icx = x /. First@NSolve[w[x, icy] == 0, x, Reals];
param = NDSolveValue[{
    D[{x[t], y[t]}, t] == Cross@D[w[x[t], y[t]], {{x[t], y[t]}}],
    {x[0], y[0]} == {icx, icy},
    WhenEvent[y[t] == icy && Abs[x[t] - icx] < 10^-3, 
     "StopIntegration"]
    }, {x, y}, {t, 0, Infinity}];
Graphics[{
  Black, Point@points,
  Red, Line@Transpose@Through[param["ValuesOnGrid"]]},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Very good ideas! The curve seems to fit very well. (The points are created by applying a mapping to an ellipse.)